# Nuget Package Icon Not getting Displayed

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I'm developing an Nuget Package. I have `icon.png` placed inside `Images` folder inside my package code. In my `.csproj` file I have added required tags related to icon. But still icon is not getting displayed. Instead default blue icon is displayed in Nuget.

Here is my `.csproj` file,

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <PackageIcon>icon.png</PackageIcon>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="Images\icon.png" Pack="true" PackagePath=""/>
</ItemGroup>
```

Am I missing anything? please assist.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Currently, displaying the icon by using the `<PackageIcon/>` or `<icon/>` property on packages showed on NuGet in Visual Studio is not supported. You can preview your package icon in the upload preview in https://nuget.org

The tracking issue for supporting embedded icons in NuGet for Visual Studio is: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/8189

Comment: According tracking issue, Microsoft release this functionality in 5.5.0.6392 version of NuGet.Client. So, it will released in NuGet PM UI in Visual Studio soon.

Comment: "soon" one year later and it still doesn't work.