# MyGet doesn't show nuget package Self-contained icons

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, myget

I've been migrating our nuget packages to using Self-contained icons support. When I publish them to MyGet, we're not seeing the icon image in Visual Studio package manager UI.

Is this a bug? Has anyone else published a nuget package to MyGet using self-contained icons and they show in the VS package manager UI?

Comment: Hi Pure, any update about this issue?

Comment: I haven't had a chance to check, yet. when i will, i'll report back.

Comment: Well.I am always here and hope your any feeback.

Comment: any update about this issue, please check if my answer helps you handle the issue or not. If it helps, please do not forget to [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). And if not, please feel free to let us know:)

Answer (score 1):

Sure. It is an issue and check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61593626/embedded-into-nuget-package-icon-doesnt-appear-in-vs/61609672#61609672). Self-contained icons which is packed into the nupkg cannot be used on the local nuget package source.

So my suggestions are that:

**Suggestions**

**One** suggestion is that you could upload your nuget package into nuget.org.

**Second** is to use icon Url. Unload your icon on a website.

New-sdk format lib pack:

```
<PackageIconUrl> https://company.com/icon.png </PackageIconUrl>
```

nuspec file with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2012/06/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata minClientVersion="3.3">
    <icon>images\icon.png</icon>
    <iconUrl>https://company.com/icon.png</iconUrl>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="..\..\icon.png" target="images\icon.png" />
  </files>
</package>
```

**Update 1**

**Actually**, `PackageIconUrl` and `iconUrl` are removed. And thanks for your guidance.

**But** when I tested in a **new-sdk** style(net core or net standard) lib project, I can use these on `csproj` file:

```
 <PropertyGroup>
        <PackageId>moqq</PackageId>
        <Version>1.0.0</Version>
        <Authors>me</Authors>
        <PackageIcon>images\test.png</PackageIcon>              
 </PropertyGroup>
 <ItemGroup>
        <None Include="mysql.png" Pack="true" PackagePath="images"></None>
 </ItemGroup>
```

That use the `PackageIcon` node seems to work. And for new-sdk project, use `dotnet pack` command line or just right-click on the project on the Solution Explorer-->**Pack**.

**Note**: My VS is **VS2019 Community 16.8.6** and if your VS2019 is too old, please update it first.

**Also**, `PackageSources5` is local feed.

[image]

**Besides**, if you used a **non-sdk** style net framework project, it actually can be done. You should use [msbuild -t:pack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package-msbuild) rather than traditional nuget pack with custom nuspec file.

**1)** install a nuget package called [NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack/) on the lib project and remember that you should use **PackageReference** format to install it. If not, you should right-click on the `packages.config` file-->**Migrate packages.config into PackageReference**.

**2)** delete `bin` and `obj` file and also `nuspec` file in your project folder, the file is redundant and if it exists, it will affect the `msbuild -t:pack`.

**3)** add these on the `csproj` file at the bottom of the `csproj` file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
        <PackageId>moqqq</PackageId>
        <Version>1.0.0</Version>
        <Authors>me</Authors>
        <PackageIcon>images\test.png</PackageIcon>
        <PackageIconUrl></PackageIconUrl> 
         
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
        <None Include="test.png" Pack="true" PackagePath="images"></None> 
</ItemGroup>
```

You could also add on `csproj` file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
<GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
</PropertyGroup>
```

**After that**, click `Rebuild` button and it could generate the nupkg file under `project folder\Debug or Release\`.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Perry - thanks for the reply! Ok, so I can't publish to nuget.org (these are private nugets). 2nd, the `PackageIconUrl` is deprecated (ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#packageiconurl) so we shouldn't be using this. So this is -really- confusing! I understand that we can use both ways, but .. when `iconUrl` is 100% removed, then what? we're all using broken icon-less packages?

Comment: You should change to use another pack function and it works well with `PackageIcon` in my side. Please see my updated answer:)

Comment: @Pure.Krome, any update about it? That test it will not take a long time. And we hope your any feedback:)